# How can I get all the comments, added to shared link of my website on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, get, comments, share, facebook-like

Question:
I have a "like" button on my website, someone clicks it and shares url of my website with his comment.This is posted to Facebook. Some users add comments to this post with shared url.
Can I get all those comments?
If yes,then how?

Answer (score 0):

If the user has authenticated with your application and granted read_stream permission you could by requesting /me/feed and looking for your site.  But otherwise, no, not just by them sharing/liking your page.